# Accessing state inside .jsx element

Tags: javascript, react-native

If I have an element like this:

```
const CardWebView = () => {
  const url = 'xxx';

  return (
    <WebView
    source={{
      uri: url,
    }}
    onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
    startInLoadingState
    javaScriptEnabled
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
  />
  );
};
```

How do I use `state` to change the `url`, for example?

I've tried `var url = this.state.url` but this gives me an error. This specific portion of code uses arrow functions and I'm not too familiar with them.

Comment: This is functional component, so there is no `this.state`

Comment: You should use React Hooks on Functional Component https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @AbdulsametKurt Thanks for letting me know about functional components and react hooks. I just changed it so that it's no longer a functional component. This may not be an option for everyone though, so add that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use React Hooks on Functional Component - [Using the State Hook – React](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a React.Component with a render method. You can't have state if you're not in a component

```
const CardWebView = <CardWebView />

class CardWebView extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {url: 'xxx'};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
      source={{
        uri: this.state.url,
      }}
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
      startInLoadingState
      javaScriptEnabled
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    />
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: you can with react hooks, specifically with useState hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: I know it, but he said that he doesn't want to use hooks and he changed the question so that is no longer a functional component

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use state from a functional component, you need to use the [useState hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

It is fairly simple to use, just define the initial value, the callback to change it and the name of the state variable and you're set. Then you can use the callback to alter the state variable whenever you need to.

a simple example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {

  const [url, setUrl] = useState('something')

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{url}</Text>
      <Text onPress={() => setUrl('something new')}>Click me</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```